# How do I add an icon for an installed application to one of the MIUI app icon screens?

Tags: restore, delete, app-icons, miui-12.5, xiaomi-mi9

My friend is using a device running MIUI 12.5.1.

They have installed some app, and then some kind of magic happened, in which they were told by the device that it would be cleaning up / removing icons of unused applications - even though the app had been used; and the icon went away. Now, they want to restore the icon. The app appears to be installed when examining Settings | Apps | Manage Apps.

My friend reports they can't find the icon anywhere, i.e. hasn't just been moved (although TBH when they told me this I got suspicious it's in some folder they're missing).

How can I restore the app icon? I've searched the Settings, and have not found anywhere this might be possible; app screen customization also only offers widgets, not app icons.

Comment: What does reinstalling the app does? Does it not automatically create an app icon on the stock home screen?

Comment: "*... then deleted the icon for that app ...*". There's no way to delete the icon of an installed app. Some launcher apps allow (un)hiding the icons though.

Comment: Not familiar with MIUI, but was the icon removed from the home screen? Also, is there an app launcher/drawer that shows all the installed apps? The general approach is to long hold the app icon from the app launcher/drawer, then drag and drop it to the home screen.

Comment: "is there an app launcher/drawer that shows all the installed apps" <- No, that's the problem.

Comment: @Firelord: I was trying to avoid reinstallation, for reasons, but I'll tell my friend to try this. Also, see edit.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: You're actually right... see edit.